# Django: pass 'choices' from another database to a MultipleChoiceField

Tags: python, django

I have a model which has a field that is supposed to be a multi select. I have created a `ModelForm` for this. In this, I query another database to obtain the possible options a user should be able to choose from.

```
class CollaborationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    cursor = connections['diseases'].cursor()
    cursor.execute('select some_column from some_table')
    all_cuis = cursor.fetchall()
    cui = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=all_cuis, help_text='Relevant CUI, can select more than one')

    class Meta:
        model = Collaboration
        fields = '__all__'
```

`MultipleChoiceField` only takes a tuple as choices argument. It just so happens that this is exactly what `cursor.fetchall()` returns. The only issue is that this tuple looks something like this:

```
(('value1',), ('value2',),...))
```

Since there is no second value in the tuple django throws an error:

```
not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

A tuple is supposed to be immutable, so I feel like somehow adding the same value again to make the error go away is very hacky. On the other hand, making the tuple into a list, and then into a tuple again also seems wrong. Is there a better approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need key-value pairs, like:

```
class CollaborationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    cursor = connections['diseases'].cursor()
    cursor.execute('select some_column from some_table')
    all_cuis = cursor.fetchall()
    cui = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        choices=[(c[0],c[0]) for c in all_cuis],
        help_text='Relevant CUI, can select more than one'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Collaboration
        fields = '__all__'
```

Note however that here you will only run the query *once* when you load the `CollaborationForm` class. You might want to move the creation of the choices to the `__init__` method. For example:

```
class CollaborationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    cui = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        choices=[],
        help_text='Relevant CUI, can select more than one'
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        cursor = connections['diseases'].cursor()
        cursor.execute('select some_column from some_table')
        all_cuis = cursor.fetchall()
        self.fields['cui'].choices = [c*2 for c in all_cuis]

    class Meta:
        model = Collaboration
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: So quick..! If I use `[(c,c) for c in all_cuis]` it complains about too _many_ values though. `[(c[0],c[0]) for c in all_cuis]` did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @Snackoverflow: or you can make use of `c*2` to make tuples that contain the items twice.

Comment: I didn't know that was a thing :). Seems to work just fine as well and looks cleaner. Thanks again.